# Symfony2 Cookie Problems when trying to get the cookie

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, request, response

I'm having difficulties in managing Cookies in Symfony2.

All my data is manipulated in an Controller used as service for another Controller (I have tested outside this controller and I have the same issue).

I use the followings:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
```

To set a Cookie, I use **Cookie()** and **Response()**

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $cookie     = new Cookie('mycookie', 'myvalue' );
    $response   = new Response();
    $response->headers->setCookie( $cookie );
    $response->send();

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:default.html.twig', array());

}
```

All is ok here, I can view the Cookie dumping a **$_COOKIE** var and I can see it using various browser plugins. But the problem is that I cannot read/get it.

I tried 2 methods, none of them were successful.

```
public function readAction()
{

    // Method 1
    $request = new Request;
    $cookies = $request->cookies;
    var_dump( $cookies->get('mycookie') );

    // Method 2
    $response = new Response();
    $cookies = $response->headers->getCookies();
    var_dump($cookies);

    // Return My Response

}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?
To be noticed that I am just starting using Symfony2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new `Request` & `Response` object instead of using pre-initialized ones. Try in this way,

```
public function readAction(Request $request) // <-- Notice the change
{

    // Method 1
    $cookies = $request->cookies;
    var_dump( $cookies->get('mycookie') );

    // Method 2
    $response = $this->getResponse();         // <-- Notice the change
    $cookies = $response->headers->getCookies();
    var_dump($cookies);

    // Return My Response

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do the job... I'm new in symfony so maybe I'm not getting the whole idea right. The "readAction" is a Controller, if I try to requested from URL I get the missed argument error. If I try to access it as a service I have no request object from the method I request it....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Apul Gupta. From your answer I got something like this:

```
public function readAction(Request $request)
{
    $mycookie = $request->cookies->get('mycookie');
    var_dump( $mycookie  );
}
```

From the controller, I request the readAction

```
$generic = $this->get('generic');
$generic->readAction( $this->getRequest() ); // added this code here because the controller as service don't get the "getRequest()" method
```

Thank you